# Is there any URL available that shows only Mails of Gmail Inbox?

Tags: gmail, url

I want to display my Gmails in Google Gadget. So, after getting Sign In, is there any url available that directly display the mail header of my Gmail Inbox ?

EDIT : I want to display emails of my personal mail domain on my website homepage.